# Mismatched Subnets, what could possibly to wrong (and to what extent)?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, gateway, switching

I have two routers at home, one from my employer (LAN IP locked to 192.168.0.1/16) and another from my ISP, which I have put on 192.168.0.4/16. Both the routers are connected to a dumb switch, which in turn is connected to two physical interfaces on a pfSense machine.

The pfSense machine has two WAN interfaces with :

WAN 1 : IP : 192.168.0.2/30 Gateway : 192.168.0.1

WAN 2 : IP 192.168.0.5/30 Gateway : 192.168.0.4

I know this is a potential subnet mismatch, and there are various reasons for which I am being forced to do such a setup as of now (shared apartment, lack of a managed switch, pfSense policies on multiple gateways on same subnet/interface). Also, I do not need access to any device falling out of the /30 subnet bounds, just I need access to the two gateway IPs.

What are the potential issues with this setup, specifically relating to L2 and L3 issues ? (Given this is an isolated network segment with non-internet routable spaces)

Comment: Probably no problems, but why even bother with the extra switch?

Comment: As long as you can guarantee no IP addresses will go outside 192.168.0.*/30, you should be fine. And I second the "why a dumb switch" question - does one router need to talk to the other router directly? I guess the pfSense setup would be easier if one router would be directly connected to one WAN interface, and the other to the other.

Comment: Yes, some clients connected to router 1 directly need to access router 2 for some static routes, hence the two routers need to be connected together. The switch is just there cause Router 1 has only 1 LAN port, and many users need a wired connection to the router.